# What sense does it make to ask for the a#- (b-) minor scale pattern before learning a-minor tab?

Tags: discussion

The question is related to this one:

[What is the scale of A # Minor / B flat minor? What does it look like in tab?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/83141/what-is-the-scale-of-a-minor-b-flat-minor-what-does-it-look-like-in-tab)

I would agree with The comment of Tim to transpose up the a- minor scale (or the b-minor down).

Then I thought there would be a problem with open strings in the first „position“. But there are other frets to start with, e.g. the 5th.

I think it would be better to understand the tuning system of a guitar and the pattern of the minor  scales in general.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: It made (makes) little sense to me too. Any tune that can be played in Bbm is also playable in Am, especially for , as OP stated, a beginner. I'm missing something too...

Comment: Then we could close my question as not important and add a pedagogical comment there? ;)

Comment: I haven‘t seen that the question was edited and Tim‘s comment was hidden below.

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking us to speculate on why another user asked the question they asked? I'm assuming they have their reasons, but you'd have to ask them what those reasons are.

Comment: If '@jasmine' is reading, she could enlighten us.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - it does indeed seem an odd thing for a beginner to need to do - answer could have been 'put capo on fret 1, play Am notes'. I certainly wouldn't be teaching A#m to anyone before Am - would you? Even in 6th position.

Comment: @Todd, we can delete my  question. I always wonder why questions like this are going through while  mine are closed as off topic and unclear or too broad or opinion based ... and why there is not a principle to give answers that teach how to fish instead of giving a fish.  But then more often I found that as say „they have their reason“. Well, and I have mine. „Or am I missing something“ wasn’t  meant ironical.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli What is the "problem" with open strings?